# Using href links inside <option> tag

Tags: html, forms, tags, anchor, html-select

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select name="forma">
    <option value="Home">Home</option>
    <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
    <option value="Sitemap">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

How can I make **Home**, **Contact** and **Sitemap** values as links?
I used the following code and as I expected it didn't work:

```
<select name="forma">
    <option value="Home"><a href="home.php">Home</a></option>
    <option value="Contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></option>
    <option value="Sitemap"><a href="sitemap.php">Sitemap</a></option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can simply follow  helpfollowing link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287672/links-in-select-dropdown-options
Hope that may help

Comment: Maybe this non javascript solution would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu/24718890#24718890

Answer (score 339, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022: This answer is fine but really in 2022 we shouldn't be doing this anymore!**

**UPDATE (May 2020):** Someone asked in the comments why I wouldn't advocate this solution. I guess it's a question of semantics. I'd rather my users navigate using `<a>` and kept `<select>` for making form selections because HTML elements have semantic meeting and they have a purpose, `anchors` take you places, `<select>` are for picking things from lists.

Consider, if you are viewing a page with a non-traditional browser (a non graphical browser or screen reader or the page is accessed programmatically, or JavaScript is disabled) what then is the "meaning" or the "intent" of this `<select>` you have used for navigation? It is saying "please pick a page name" and not a lot else, certainly nothing about navigating. The easy response to this is `well i know that my users will be using IE or whatever so shrug` but this kinda misses the point of semantic importance.

Whereas a funky drop-down UI element made of suitable layout elements (and some js) containing some regular  anchors still retains it intent even if the layout element is lost, "these are a bunch of links, select one and we will navigate there".

Here is an article on [the misuse and abuse of `<select>`](https://uxmovement.com/forms/stop-misusing-select-menus/).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
<select name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
 <option value="Home.php">Home</option>
 <option value="Contact.php">Contact</option>
 <option value="Sitemap.php">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE (Nov 2015):** In this day and age if you want to have a drop menu there are plenty of arguably [better ways to implement one.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown) This answer is a direct answer to a direct question, but I don't advocate this method for public facing web sites.

Comment: Just change the values to home.php, contact.php and sitemap.php.

Comment: very cool!  you can use this code with `<option value="#anchor_on_my_site">...</option>` to link to an anchor as well!

Comment: I know this is very trivial but should be "onchange" and not "ONCHANGE"

Comment: wish that I woulda found this 1hr ago. was stuck on this. and stackoverflow was down! so had to use other sites rummaging for the answer.

Comment: How can i make the selected item is selected?                 <select class="form-control" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">   
            <option value="?type=1">
             Change Management Projects
            </option>
            <option value="?type=2">
             L &amp; D Projects
            </option>
          </select>

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, maybe you should consider creating a separate stackoverflow question, referencing this one?

Comment: re @pruett, you can also use `value="?query_string"` to tack a query onto the current page

Comment: You can shorten it to `location = this.value;`

Comment: Any idea how this will influence SEO? Will the links be crawable by search engines?

Comment: @kasperTaeymans probably badly as it is, as a few people have noted, a misuse of form fields. Frankly I'm amazed this still gets so much attention as drop-navs and flyout navs have moved on so far.

Comment: just to let you know your link doesnt work for ways to implement one

Comment: `I don't advocate this method for public facing web sites` what are the reasons?

Comment: I guess it's a question of semantics. I'd rather my users navigate using <a> and used <select> to make form selections because HTML elements have semantic meeting and they have a purpose, anchors take you places, <select> are for picking things. Consider, if you are viewing a page with a non-traditional browser (a non graphical browser or screen reader or it is be accessed programmatically, or JavaScript disabled) what is the "meaning" of this <select>? Not a lot. Where as a drop-down made of JavaScript and suitable layout elements containing some regular <a> anchors still retains it intent.

Comment: i guess all your points are dead accurate, don't use this on a <b>normal</b> webpage. but since flatpress hasn't implemented something like this, i need to give my blog viewers a nice overview - so actually this solution is good!

Comment: this is a jump menu which will make a problem in the accessibility...

Comment: Note: Doesn't work in 2022 anymore.

Comment: @AhmedMansour yes you are correct, no one should be building public facing websites like this anymore

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan can you expand on this? In which version of what does this break? (all else being equal the Gregorian calendar year shouldn't break this)

Comment: Not sure why you are talking about the Gregorian calendar, this doesn't work on my Google Chrome 98, Windows 10 Pro. I simply copy-pasted the code without any changes (I do have JavaScript enabled).

Answer (score 25):

You cant use href tags within option tags. You will need javascript to do so.

```
<select name="formal" onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">
<option value="home">Home</option>
<option value="contact">Contact</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function handleSelect(elm)
  {
     window.location = elm.value+".php";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

Use a real dropdown menu instead: a list (`ul`, `li`) and links. Never misuse form elements as links.

Readers with screen readers usually scan through a automagically generated list of links – the’ll miss these important information. Many keyboard navigation systems (e.g. JAWS, Opera) offer different keyboard shortcuts for links and form elements.

If you still cannot drop the idea of a `select` don’t use the `onchange` handler at least. This is a real pain for keyboard users, it makes your third item nearly inaccessible.

Comment: toscho is correct of course, makmour's application is a massive misuse of form fields.

Comment: Right, but what about mobile devices ?  If the accepted answer is coupled with an actual dropdown menu with a "display: hidden" switch on media query, are your concerns still valid ?  Or do you have a better solution ?

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou The better solution is to use just one menu with actual links in it.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution looks good, but there is one case it cannot handle:

The "onchange" event will not be triggered when the same option is reselected. So, I came up with the following improvement:

HTML

```
<select id="sampleSelect" >
  <option value="Home.php">Home</option>
  <option value="Contact.php">Contact</option>
  <option value="Sitemap.php">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
$("select").click(function() {
  var open = $(this).data("isopen");
  if(open) {
    window.location.href = $(this).val()
  }
  //set isopen to opposite so next time when use clicked select box
  //it wont trigger this event
  $(this).data("isopen", !open);
});
```

Comment: Or just add an empty option in the beginning: `<option value="">&nbsp;</option>`

Answer (score 5):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment on toscho's answer.)

I have no experience with screen readers and I'm sure your points are valid.

However as far as using a keyboard to manipulate selects, it is trivial to select any option by using the keyboard:

TAB to the control

SPACE to open the select list

UP or DOWN arrows to scroll to the desired list item

ENTER to select the desired item

Only on ENTER does the onchange or (JQuery .change()) event fire.

While I personally would not use a form control for simple menus, there are many web applications that use form controls to change the presentation of the page (eg., sort order.) These can be implemented either by AJAX to load new content into the page, or, in older implementations, by triggering new page loads, which is essentially a page link.

IMHO these are valid uses of a form control.

Answer (score 4):

```
    <select name="career" id="career" onchange="location = this.value;">
        <option value="resume" selected> All Applications </option>
        <option value="resume&j=14">Seo Expert</option>
        <option value="resume&j=21">Project Manager</option>
        <option value="resume&j=33">Php Developer</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

The `<select>` tag creates a dropdown list.  You can't put html links inside a dropdown.

However, there are JavaScript libraries that provide similar functionality.  Here is one example:  http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/dropmenuindex.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone can make a better answer than this with Jquery where the change in the dropdown will lead to a new page (good for navigation control on a navbar).

```
<td><select name="forma" id='SelectOption'>
            <option value="Home"><a href="home.php">Home</a></option>
            <option value="Contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></option>
            <option value="Sitemap"><a href="sitemap.php">Sitemap</a></option>
        </select></td><td>
```

```
document.getElementById('SelectOption').addEventListener('change', function() {
  val = $( "#SelectOption" ).val();
    
  console.log(val)
  if(val === 'Home') {
    window.open('home.php','_blank');
    }
  if(val === 'Contact') {
    window.open('contact.php', '_blank');
  }
  if (val === 'Sitemap') {
    window.open('sitemap.php', '_blank');
  }
});
```