# Code Igniter: How do I add these anchor tags to a dropdown menu?

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

This is probably pretty simple but I am new to this.

All I want to do is put some of the current links I have working inside a dropdown menu.

Here are the working links I would like to display in a dropdown:

```
<p>
<?=anchor('tasks/AddTask', 'Add a Task')?>
<?=anchor('tasks', 'All Tasks')?>
<?=anchor('tasks/mjh', 'Mike')?>
<?=anchor('tasks/ejm', 'Ed')?>
<?=anchor('tasks/fjb', 'Jan')?>
<?=anchor('tasks/ctk', 'Colin')?>
<?=anchor('tasks/cgb', 'Cindy')?>
</p>
```

The following does not seem to work:

```
<form>
<p>
Change View:
<select>
<option value="tasks">All Tasks</option>
<option value="tasks/mjh">Mike</option>
<option value="tasks/ejm">Ed</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</p>
</form>
```

Or:

```
<form>
<p>
    Change View:
    <select>
    <option><?=anchor('tasks', 'All Tasks')?></option>
    <option><?=anchor('tasks/mjh', 'Mike')?></option>
    <option><?=anchor('tasks/ejm', 'Ed')?></option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</p>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are using short tags `<?=` are they enabled through php.ini in the first place?

Comment: I assume so.  The first set of code containing the anchor() tags works.  I now just want to have those links appear in a dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor tags won't work as they create full hyperlinks, and not just the URL. The following should work:

```
<select id="my_links" name="my_links">
    <option value="<?php echo site_url('some/path'); ?>"><?php echo site_url('some/path'); ?</option>
</select>
```

Then you could use a bit of Javacsript to redirect the browser to the specified URL.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

[using href links inside <option> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

It uses a bit of javascript and plain old HTML rather than the CodeIgniter helper, but should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use javascript.

```
<select onchange="document.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
   <option value="<?php echo site_url('the/path'); ?>">All Tasks</option>
   <option value="<?php echo site_url('the/path'); ?>">Mike</option>
   <option value="<?php echo site_url('the/path'); ?>">Ed</option>
</select>
```