# Execute Javascript function from html select

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a simple html select tag with some options attached:

```
<select>
<option>school a</option>
<option>school b</option>
<option>school c</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to attach some simple event handlers to the options the same way I would to say... a link:

```
<option onclick="scheduleA();">school a</option>
```

Do I need to construct a separate Javascript function to deal with event handling in this situation or is there some quick html that will accomplish this task?

Comment: Take a look at `onchange`. You cuold write one function with parameter.

Comment: There your go my friend
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag

Comment: Thanks Alex, I didn't see this before I posted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You would be better off assigning `onChange="schedule(this.value);` on the `<select>`. Partly because it actually works, partly to avoid redundant code if the same option is selected twice, partly because fewer event handlers is always better.

Comment: @kjarsenal: If you're supporting older versions of IE, just be sure to give each `option` element its own `value` attribute. Older IE won't automatically substitute the text content of the `option` when you don't give it a value attribute.

Comment: noted. those values will be generated dynamically by the framework. thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Use an `onchange` event on the `select`

```
<select onchange="scheduleA.call(this, event)">
```

Then in your handler...

```
function scheduleA(event) {
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/hYY6X/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's was helpfully

Answer (score 1):

use onchange instead

```
<select onchange="schedule(this.value)">
<option>school a</option>
<option>school b</option>
</select>

function schedule(selectedValue){
     ... do something with selectedValue
}
```

Comment: That maybe, except the answer wasn't there when I loaded the page... If anything it re-enforces the fact it's a suitable solution. Moderators feel free to delete or whatever. I haven't been here that long but I really do get the impression there is a bit of an attitude I dislike from the community - hardly encouraging

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done:

```
<span class="text-left" hidden>{{ fullNameExists(concern.user) }}</span>
```

It will invoke it. You can even hide it with hidden preventıng result being visible to users.

```
<client-only>
<span class="text-left" hidden>{{ fullNameExists(concern.user) }}</span>
</client-only>
```