# How to make a pure css based dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am looking horizontal dropdown menu pure css based and browser compatible....

i am looking like mentioned below example

[image]

Comment: go and google for ` pure css drop down` . btw without `javscript` it would be complex

Comment: @Sumant hi where is this navi can you send me link proper.

Comment: go with the @Shailender Arora answer its fine

Comment: purely CSS dropdown menus are hard to use for everybody and less accessible for disabled people than JS+CSS menus: 1 pixel off the submenu for 1 millisecond and your submenu closes immediately. Sigh.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

see this is pure css bases dropdown menu:-

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About Us</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">The Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Products</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Cozy Couch</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Great Table</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Small Chair</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Shiny Shelf</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Invisible Nothing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Right Here</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Somewhere Else</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

li ul
{
    display: none;
}

ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #2C5463;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover 
{
    background: #617F8A;
}
li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a 
{
    background: #617F8A;
}

li:hover li a:hover 
{
    background: #95A9B1;
}
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/7/

Comment: has anybody else tried it in all browsers? is this multi browser compatible?

Comment: Doesn't work on mobile only because `:hover` is hard on mobile. Easy to add a line of javascript that shows the menu on click.

Answer (score 3):

```css
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */
.navigation {
  width: 150px;
}

/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */
.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */
.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

/* add hover behaviour */
.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}


/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
  display the submenu inside it.
  we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
*/

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

/*
  we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
  CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
*/

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}

/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */
.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
  we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
*/
.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="nav.css">
</head>
</body>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested in IE7 - 9 and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/WCaKg/. Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>

    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>

    <li>&lt;li&gt;

        <ul>
            <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>

            <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>

            <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>

            <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>

    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>

    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 200%/1.5 Optima, 'Lucida Grande', Lucida, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  width: 9em;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  background: #60c;
  background: rgba(102, 0, 204, 0.66);
  border: 4px solid #60c;
  color: #fff;
}
li:hover {
  position: relative;
}

ul ul {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
  width: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.33);
}

li:hover ul {
  top: 2em;
  left: 3px;
}

li li {
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  background: #909;
  background: rgba(153, 0, 153, 0.66);
  border: 3px solid #909;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

View code online on: [WebCrafts.org](http://www.webcrafts.org/crafts/temp/2/)

HTML code:

> ```
> <body id="body">
> <div id="navigation">
>     <h2>
>         Pure CSS Drop-down Menu
>     </h2>
>   <div id="nav" class="nav">
>     <ul>
>         <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
>         <li>
>             <a href="#">Menu2</a>
>           <ul>
>                 <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu1</a></li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a href="#">Sub-Menu2</a>
>                   <ul>
>                         <li><a href="#">Demo1</a></li>
>                       <li><a href="#">Demo2</a></li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </li>
>                 <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu3</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu4</a></li>
>             </ul>
>         </li>
>         <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
>         <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
>     </ul>
>   </div>
> </div>
> </body>
> ```

Css code:

```
body{
    background-color:#111;
}

#navigation{
    text-align:center;
}
#navigation h2{
    color:#DDD;
}

.nav{
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:5;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.nav ul{
    width:auto;
    list-style:none;
}

.nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#222;
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:gray;
}

.nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#EEC;   
}
.nav ul li ul{
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}

.nav ul li ul li{
    display:block;
}

.nav ul li ul li ul{
    margin-left:100%;
    margin-top:-30px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.nav ul li ul li:hover ul{
    margin-left:100%;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create simple drop-down menu using HTML and CSS

CSS:

```
<style>
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View demo online](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to always use `ul` elements to achieve that, you can use other elements too as seen below. Here there are 2 examples, one using `div` and one using `select`.

This examples demonstrates the basic functionality, but can be extended/enriched more. It is tested in linux only (iceweasel and chrome).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<style>
.drop_container
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
.always_visible
{
  background-color:#FAFAFA;
  color:#333333;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px silver solid;
  margin:0px;
  margin-right:5px;
  font-size:14px;
  font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.always_visible:hover + .hidden_container
{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  color:green;
}
.hidden_container
{
  display:none;
  border:1px gray solid;
  left:0px;
  background-color:#FAFAFA;
  padding:5px;
  z-index:1;
}
.hidden_container:hover
{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
.link
{
  color:blue;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:3px;
  display:block;
}
.link:hover
{
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
}
.line_1
{
  width:800px;
  border:1px tomato solid;
  padding:5px;
}
</style>      
</head>

<body>

<div class="line_1">
<div class="drop_container">
  <select class="always_visible" disabled><option>Select</option></select>
  <div class="hidden_container">
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option_ 1</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option__ 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option___ 3</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option____ 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <select class="always_visible" disabled><option>Select</option></select>
  <div class="hidden_container">
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">____1</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">___2</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">__3</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">_4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="line_1">
 <div class="drop_container">
  <div class="always_visible">Select___</div>
  <div class="hidden_container">
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option_ 1</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option__ 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option___ 3</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option____ 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="drop_container">
  <div class="always_visible">Select___</div>
  <div class="hidden_container">
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option_ 1</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option__ 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option___ 3</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.gr" class="link">Option____ 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is different ways to make dropdown menu using css. Here is simple code.

HTML Code

```
    <label class="dropdown">

  <div class="dd-button">
    Dropdown
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input" id="test">

  <ul class="dd-menu">
    <li>Dropdown 1</li>
    <li>Dropdown 2</li>
  </ul>

</label>
```

CSS Code

```
body {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

a:hover {
  color: #222222
}

/* Dropdown */

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dd-button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dd-button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.dd-button:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}


.dd-input {
  display: none;
}

.dd-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dd-input + .dd-menu {
  display: none;
} 

.dd-input:checked + .dd-menu {
  display: block;
} 

.dd-menu li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dd-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.dd-menu li a {
  display: block;
  margin: -10px -20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dd-menu li.divider{
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

More [css code example](https://www.csscodelab.com/)