# Javascript to make dropdown menus on hover state - no hard-coding in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

Thanks in advance. I have actually tried several javascript scripts to get this to work and none have, but my understanding of javascript is pretty rudimentary.

I cannot adjust the code of the link itself - it is being generated. But it is generated with an id and a class. I would like to have a script in the document that references the link's id so that when the user rolls over the link, a hidden ul (or div) appears - like a normal css navigation dropdown but, again, i cannot alter the code of the actual links. I can only alter the CSS in general.

Is there javascript that can do this? I can do query..

Thank you again!

bb

Comment: Brr, dropdown menus on hover. >< I wish you won't ever have to use that on a touch device

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: now used to this link http://www.devinrolsen.com/wp-content/themes/dolsen/demos/css/infinite-sub-menu/ for navi

Comment: check to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu for you .......

Comment: "Is there javascript that can do this?" Yes, there are plenty ready-to-use solutions out there. Just pick the one that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done drop down menu using HTML and CSS only, which show/hide on menu link hover state.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu1" class="menu">
  <a href="#" id="link1">
    Menu-1
  </a>
  <div id="menulist1" class="menulist">
    <div>
      Option1
    </div>
    <div>
      Option2
    </div>
    <div>
      Option3
    </div>
    <div>
      Option4
    </div>
    <div>
      Option5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="menu">
  <a href="#" id="link2">
    Menu-2
  </a>
  <ul id="menulist2" class="menulist">
    <li>
      Option1
    </li>
    <li>
      Option2
    </li>
    <li>
      Option3
    </li>
    <li>
      Option4
    </li>
    <li>
      Option5
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
  font-size:15px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.menu a{
  display:block;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#2211ce;
  color:#dccb00;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#menulist1{
  position:absolute;
  top:33px;
  border:1px solid #113399;
  background-color:#88a5ff;
  display:none;
}
#menulist2{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  border:1px solid #113399;
  background-color:#88a5ff;
  display:none;
}
#menu1:hover #menulist1{
  display:block;
}

#menu2:hover #menulist2{
  margin-top:13px;
  display:block;
}

.menulist div{
  margin-left:0px;
  padding:3px;
  width:112px;
}
.menulist li{
  list-style:none;
  width:72px;
  padding:3px;
  margin-left:0px;
  display:block;
}

.menulist div:hover,.menulist li:hover{
  background-color:#1155ac;
  color:#dccb00;
}
```

I have also done bins for above example, please click on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbo

Comment: Hello all, thank you so much. I went away fro July 4th and didn't expect such prompt replies.

Comment: oops.. So I do understand how to make a list that dropsdown on hover.  But I haven't gotten it to work. However, I will try again and report back, maybe I am just missing something there. Thank you.