# May someone explain this html/css code to me?

Tags: html, css

How come when this code is run, it creates a drop-down list like it does?

**HTML**

```
   <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About Us</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">The Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Products</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Cozy Couch</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Great Table</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Small Chair</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Shiny Shelf</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Invisible Nothing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Right Here</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Somewhere Else</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #2C5463;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #617F8A;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #617F8A;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #95A9B1;
}
```

I know all the CSS properties and the HTML tags used in the above code, but still, for somee reason, I've been trying for the past hour and still not been able to completely comprehend it.
Source: [How to make a pure css based dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu)

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Most probably, the CSS. The code is changing just the appearance, how is it resulting in a drop-down menu?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: seriously, read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically adds style to an unordered list so that it looks and behaves like a menu.

This is the part that displays each list item as a menu entry

```
ul li {
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
}
```

This is the part that hides the submenus

```
li ul {
display: none;
}
```

And this is the part that shows a submenu when moving the mouse over each main menu entry

```
li:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

The rest is just for formatting fonts and colors.

Comment: Got it. One more thing, actually two:
How may I go about underlining every list (Home, About Us) with a color and some width whenever someone hovers there?
Also, will it be better to create a drop-down menu with JavaScript?

Comment: @AkshatTripathi : In the section `ul li a:hover {...}` add `text-decoration: underline;`. As for javascript versus css... that's up to you. Personally, I'd go for css because that's the most simple solution and not all users have javascript enabled in their browsers. But that depends on the complexity of your project and your skills in javascript and css.

Answer (score 0):

At a hover on the li it'll set the display of the UL to block which will show the dropdown for the item.

```
li ul {
display: none;
}
```

It's hidden...