# Creating A Drop-down Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been having a problem. I can't get a drop-down to work at all, I've tried tutorials and other various sources on the internet with no luck. So I've decided to try and see if someone can help me.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="pilot-main-login">
            <img src="css/images/pilotloginicon.png">
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Operations</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Pilot Application</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">VX Tracker</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #E20000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #292827;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #292827;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #292827;
}

.nav{
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li{
    line-height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav  a:hover{
    background-color: #D40000;
}

.nav a{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think that it is the norm to use JavaScript to make the dropdown work. Do you have any JS code?

Comment: Consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu

Comment: I don't, I'm not super familiar with JS either.

Comment: You want it to drop on mouse hover only? if you need to bind click event you'll need JS..

Comment: I need it to be when you mouse over the li, a drop-down comes down and then choose another li. Pretty standard drop-down. Here is the site: http://vxavirtual.us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/gDy5c/) out

I have used the HTML you posted and added a submenu to "Operations" list item. When you are creating a simple drop-down on hover, make the main menu items `position: relavtive`. Make the submenu items `ul` `absolute position` and position properties like `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` to position the submenu items where you want to display when it is hovered and make the subemnu items `ul` hidden by using `display:none`. Now on hover you can make the the sub-menu items `ul` visible using `display: block`.

HTML used

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="pilot-main-login">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" />
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Operations</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub menu 1</li>
                    <li>Sub menu 2</li>
                    <li>Sub menu 3</li>
                </ul>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Pilot Application</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">VX Tracker</a>
                </li><li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS used

```
.pilot-main-login{
    float:left;
}

.nav-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #E20000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #292827;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #292827;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #292827;
}

.nav{
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

nav{
    float:left;
}

.nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li{
    line-height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.nav li a{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav  a:hover{
    background-color: #D40000;
}

.nav a{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
// Styles for the sub menu item
.nav li > ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    padding:0;
    background-color:yellow;
}
// To display submenu items on hover
.nav li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Hope this might help you.
Also if you have sub menus for the sub menu better names the `ul` items using class names. For eg:

```
<li><a href="#">Operations</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub menu 1</li>
        <li>Sub menu 2</li>
        <li><a>Sub menu 3</a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
               <li>Sub sub menu 1</li>
               <li>Sub sub menu 2</li>
            </ul
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This will help you style the sub menu items as you need.

Comment: This works exactly how I want! I have one problem though, there is a image slider just below the navigation bar, the drop-down menu is going behind the slider! Any suggestions?

Comment: use `z-index` for the dropdown menu. eg: `z-index:10`. Check if your slider has any z-index value. If it has, then give a higher value for the submenu `ul`.