# Making drop down menus with CSS (Is is possible)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a DropDown menu from a simple menu bar at the top of the screen just like you would see in must Applications. I think that this is possible. At the top I have the code that makes a simple menu bar across the screen.

**Question: How do I make a drop down menu in only CSS (Like you see in most application software)?**

I want it to be able to hover over the say Item1 and then have sub-items below list.

I would like to see the menu as a complete drop down so that I can add menu items to it through HTML or CSS code. The top of my page I just want to be a menu so that the user can click say on an author and then have a list of books that the can look at from a particular author.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
a
{
display:block;
width:60px;
background-color:#dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Menu3</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Trying to make a drop down menu: (This does not work it just adds more to the original menu)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
a
{
display:block;
width:60px;
background-color:#dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Menu1</a>  <-- not working
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Menu1</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Menu3</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#news">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Menu3</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Working Code from fiddle:

I am placing this code here so that if someone comes along later they can have a better reference to the code that someone has put up.

```
<ul>
    <li class="mainmenu"><a href="#home">Menu1</a> 
        <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#home">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Menu4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li {
    float:left;
}
a {
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}
li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: Also http://www.google.com/webhp?nord=1#nord=1&q=drop+down+menu+css, 8 million results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu

Comment: I like the question. I did not think that it was completely a duplicate. I am thinking that the question was referring to a very simple menu so that a person could see how it was done between the HTML and CSS sheet. There are hundreds of fancy menues that can be used but from what the question read, or at least how I interpreted it, it seemed like the individual was asking whether or not a simple menu could be made and was looking to see how it was done in more of the simple form then rather just using one found on the web. I liked the question and was using the fiddle examples as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following css

```
li ul{
position:absolute; // if you don't apply this it'll push the other menu items to right
display:none;
}

li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/cKJRQ/)

*Update*

If you want the submenu to be vertical, remove the `float:left` for `li` and add the following

```
li {
display:inline-block;
}
li ul li{
display:block;
}
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/cKJRQ/1/)

Comment: What about instead of placing them horizontally to place them vertically?

Comment: @user3491862 already added, check the update.. :)

Comment: What if you wanted to put them at the bottom of the page and have them go up instead of down. I am new to CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the submenu to hidden with `display:none;`

Then in the main menu, on hover, you want that submenu to be revealed using `.mainmenu:hover .submenu {display:block;}`

Try this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLBsp/

Comment: Nice, I love it what if you want the items to go straight down instead of across.

Comment: Straight down like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vLBsp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just enter under the title a new `UL` and keep it hidden. On hover, make it visible.
here is an a example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">index</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <li>more services
          <ul>
                <li><a href="r.php">reseller</a></li>
                <li><a href="h.php">hosting</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
     ul > li > ul{display:none;}
     ul > li:hover > ul{display:block;}
</style>
```

Using only CSS and HTML you won't be able to make this action on click, only on hover, like in the code above.