# position and float causing unexplainable behaviour in CSS dropdown

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I found the [code for a dropdown here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953516/903324) and was playing with it.

Please take a look at the following jsfiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/ArF8q/

- The first menu - `.menu` is a [normal dropdown menu that I found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953516/903324).
- The second one - `.menu2` has been modified by me.

When I remove `position:relative` from -

```
.menu ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

and remove `float:none` -

```
.menu li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

from `.menu` I get the `.menu2` which shows the dropdown in a horizontal manner.

I'm unable to understand why. I would assume that simply removing `float:none` would have made the `li` appear side by side, but we have to remove `position:relative` as well to achieve that effect. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `ul` is positioned absolute and inside the first `li` element, which is positioned relative. This causes that the `ul` is not dependent on the body element but on the `li` element. Thus it cannot be longer than the width of the `li` element so that everything inside this `ul` element is positioned as it is possible in the width of the `li` element.

Thus the problem is not the second level `li` element but the first level one.

You can work with the `>` selector to make a difference between the first level `li` and the second level one.