# dropdown menu -> HTML&CSS, hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, html-lists

i need to make dropdown menu, but im little bit newbie, so i dont know how to, can you please help me? someone?? i need to make dropdown menu from filmy_a_serialy.html
HTML code :

```
  <div id="menu">
        <ul id="ulid">
            <li class="liclass"><a href="index.html">Hlavní stránka</a></li>
            <li class="liclass"><a href="filmy_a_serialy.html">Filmy a seriály</a>
                <ul id="ulid1">
                    <li class="liclass"><a href="Filmy_a_serialy_tbb.html">TBB</a>
                </ul>
            <li class="liclass"><a href="hry_na_pc_co_me_bavi.html">Hry na PC</a>
            <li class="liclass"><a href="moje_konicky.html">Moje koníčky</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>  

ul li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 background: #0F6;
 border-radius: 0px; 
 border: 3px solid #000;    
}
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 25px;   
}
ul li:hover {
    background: #0FF;   
}
ul li:hover a {
 color: #000;
}
.liclass {
 width: 294px;
 height: 50px;
}
#ulid { 
 width: 1200px;
 height: 55px;
 margin-left: -43px;
}
```

Comment: By *help me* you mean *code it for me*?

Comment: ofc not, i have made this, i want you to help me to extend code for make dropdown menu from that filmy_a_serialy.html , i just dont know where and how to put hovers

Comment: @RostislavDanko try this - http://jsfiddle.net/kadut59h/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9953516/2240163

Comment: use this [example](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=show-hide-dropdown-on-mouse-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, your child UL needs to go at the same level as the A, both inside the LI

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="ulid">
        <li class="liclass"><a href="index.html">Hlavní stránka</a></li>
        <li class="liclass">
            <a href="filmy_a_serialy.html">Filmy a seriály</a>
            <ul id="ulid1">
                <li class="liclass"><a href="Filmy_a_serialy_tbb.html">TBB</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="liclass"><a href="hry_na_pc_co_me_bavi.html">Hry na PC</a>
        <li class="liclass"><a href="moje_konicky.html">Moje koníčky</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then try the following CSS:

```
ul li {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}
ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

This will position the sub-menu absolutely, but relative to the parent LI. It will sit 100% to the top (ie. below it) and to the left. You will probably then want to hide it until hover so:

```
ul li ul {display:none;}
ul li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

This is, of course, a very basic example! You can do some really nice stuff with dropdown menus.