# How do I create a drop down menu without nested lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I am trying to achieve a basic css drop down menu with NO nested lists within lists. In other words **the normal way is:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Blah Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The way that I need to do it is:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a><li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a><li>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a><li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a><li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to do this with purely css? Or with some basic js help?

Comment: The problem is relating the child items to the parent items with this ambiguous coding structure.

Comment: That's only one of the problems, which can be solved via a `data-parent="%parent_id%"` on the `.childitem` and an `id` on the top-level items.  The bigger question is _why_ you would want to do this.  It breaks semantics in your HTML and disassociates children from parents save for some gymnastics you'd need to perform on the elements post render.  What's the overriding need to make this unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: The other big problem is using JS to solve this would be the "real" major way to do this. WHich is unreliable because not every user allows JS so they would see a broken list. CSS is the more common way because you don't really shut that off ever. Unless you're a developer and broken.

Comment: Sure it could be done with some DOM manipulation for example, but your structure would be non-intuitive and difficult to understand. Why are you trying to do a simple thing difficult? Whats wrong with nested lists?

Comment: why try to reinvent the wheel? What factors make you say you must do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you want is actually a bit ambiguous, but there are several approaches to this.

### Solution 1 - change the DOM

If you want to change the DOM dynamically you can make use of jQuery's `nextUntil()` to find the sibling elements to move:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9afavum5/

```
// Solution 1 - change the DOM
$("ul li:not(.childitem)").each(function () {
    var children = $(this).nextUntil(":not(.childitem)");
    if (children.length) {
        $(this).append($("<ul>").append(children));
    }
});
```

This works by finding the intended parents (that do [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) have .childitem), then finding the siblings up until the next parent element using [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/).

### Soution 2 - toggle existing

If you simply want to toggle to child items, and not change the DOM, you can use similar matching techniques to find the sibling items:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9afavum5/1/

```
// Solution 2 - toggle the siblings
$("ul li.childitem").hide();
$("ul li:not(.childitem)").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(":not(.childitem)").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, "with some basic js help", you'd need just a simple 'one-liner' (in your function) to fix up the HTML, here it is *formatted* for better readability (and explanation in comments):

```js
function nestSubULbyClass(par, cls){
  for( var elms=par.getElementsByTagName('li'), L=elms.length, t
     ; L-- //loop through elements in reverse to avoid nested look-ahead loop(s)
     ; ~(' '+elms[L].className+' ').indexOf(cls)  //if   current elm contains specified class
       ? (t || (t=document.createElement('ul'))   //then take temp UL or create a new one
         ).appendChild(par.removeChild(elms[L]))  //     and move current elm to temp UL
       : t && (elms[L].appendChild(t), t=0)       //else append temp UL to current elm 
     );                                           //     and clear temp with falsy value
}

//"Make it so, number one!!"  Note this is just an example, hook and pass UL any way you like
window.onload=function(){
  nestSubULbyClass(document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0], 'childitem');
};
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**
From here on, one can now *simply use any pure css based drop-down menu (and styling) without requiring any other javascript-handlers (nice)!*

For the following *example* I used the css from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953516/588079). Note: I removed comments and formatting from the one-liner <sup>(humoring anyone arguing that non-context-aware standard formatting is better to read ☺)</sup>

```js
function nestSubULbyClass(par, cls) {
  for(var elms=par.getElementsByTagName('li'), L=elms.length, t; L--; ~(' '+elms[L].className+' ').indexOf(cls) ? (t || (t=document.createElement('ul'))).appendChild(par.removeChild(elms[L])) : t && (elms[L].appendChild(t), t=0));
}

window.onload=function(){
  nestSubULbyClass(document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0], 'childitem');
};
```

```css
ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #2C5463;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: #617F8A;
}

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a {
    background: #617F8A;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #95A9B1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What did you use to format that code? That is the least readable javascript I have seen lately, but you specifically said "Here it is formatted for better readability" so though I should ask :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I used notepad (as always) and my brain. *Without changing* the code (which would be hard to read when formatted on just one line due to horizontal length), how would you *format* it? What *my* eye sees: Ah, a utility-function containing just one body-less for-loop. The three for-sections `;` are clearly lined up between the for's `(` and `)`. Line 1 initiates necessary local variables, Line 2 is the loop-condition, making both lines clearly loop through the elements of a container that is passed. That leaves us with the third line, containing the ternary.

Comment: The ternary clearly does boolean test (and an un-informed eye should wonder.. what line starts with `?`). Likewise the `:`. If one has still missed that this is a ternary (in the same pattern as the for-loop) they should brush up their ES! So let's read that ternary: Clearly it states: "IF current element is of class 'childitem', THEN (`?`) we take our *t*emp list-container element or create a new one and move our current element to that container element. ELSE `:` IF we have a container element, we append it to the current element and clear t (I used 0 because it's shortest). Watertight loop.

Comment: The thing that's probably more interesting is why the loop goes in reverse. That's because one would otherwise need an extra "look ahead" loop. Yet in reverse we should always find an (intended) parent-element (if the shipped html-code maintains this regular format). Combined with the simple appendChild we get the correct order of the grouped sub-elements for free to. That we now also don't need a comparation in the loop-condition is just another free bonus. In other words: the "work" is not tailored to the reverse loop, instead the reverse loop is required for the simplest "work" (folding up)

Comment: I'd like to close with: I distinguish *utility functions* from *program flow*. I consider this function a utility function *used* in (more descriptive) program flow code (you'd probably shouldn't name it 'demo' however, but I'll leave the naming problem/conventions to the person using the utility function). Likewise, most people never read the libraries they include (especially if they use the automatic newest latest and greatest link).

Comment: I had to say this to: yes, instinctively placing the `?` after the boolean condition made sense, but that leaves me with `:`... should it trail (and be outside of my code-convention of prepending and might get overlooked) or prepend the ELSE (killing the vertical and consistent bool-yes-no idea). However I also usually need horizontal space for the TRUE condition.. Also, just a boolean alone makes no sense, thus it must be part of a short-circuit or a ternary. Now I have consistent vertical logic: bool, yes, no.

Comment: My concern now is that you have fully justified this formatting style, so are probably resistant to changing your style to match any existing standards. Basing your formatting on Notepad's limitations is not a strong starting point as *all* decent code editors have horizontal scrolling. You will have extreme difficulty moving to automated formatting tools (or coding with other programmers), but the main thing is that you are happy doing this. Good luck with that :)

Comment: Thanks! I figured that the lead-dev of two of my favorite games deserved a serious explanation. I would like to note however, that I *can* adapt to a team's existing coding-standards, but I can also explain/defend alternatives when choosing/deciding on new standards for a new/specific project. Still curious/interested though how you'd format the same one line of code. Offtopic: I know exactly how my ideal editor should work (a 2 column 'annotating' editor combined with Esprima for ES), but it's of-topic to ask if it exists or ask for the low-level UI-widget that this would require.

Comment: I would never code the solution to this problem as a single line of raw JavaScript. The maintenance cost would outway any benefits. Also as it is a *jQuery-tagged* question the jQuery code would be half the size and complexity. I may well add my own answer to this to illustrate (when a get some spare time) :)

Comment: The original question is ambiguous, so two solutions may be needed, but I  also just realized the initial irony of your answer `"You'd need just one line of code"`, but you then format it over *7 lines*! :>

Answer (score 0):

You can As Long as The Got Id's And Clases [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ry6mn8er/1/)

HERE

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Blah</a></li>
    <li class="drp"><a>Blah Parent</a></li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a><li>
    <li class="childitem"><a>Blah Parent</a><li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".drp").hover(function(){
       $(".childitem").slideToggle("fast");
    },function(){
         $(".childitem").hide();
  });
  $(".childitem").hover(function(){
       $(".childitem").show();
    },function(){
         $(".childitem").hide();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.drp:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;   
}
ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.childitem
{
    display: none;
}
.childitem:hover
{
    background: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is an example which uses CSS and a javascript.

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Products
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="plinkone.html">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Services
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="slinkone.html">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

 <a href="a.html">About</a>
  <a href="news.html">News</a>
  <a href="c.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

Here is the javascript:

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

    if (!x.classList.contains("responsive")) {
        x.classList.add("responsive");
    } else {

        x.classList.remove("responsive");
    }
}
</script>

and the CSS

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: ;

}

.topnav::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: ;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: ;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;   
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a big block of code! Some explanation would be nice and easy for future readers to dissect