# DROPDOWN MENU HTML

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, dropdown

I am having trouble in using dropdown in my menu. I want my menu to be able to dropdown and at the same time it hover dropdown. Will you help me with this?

Here's my code:

```css
#menu {
  float: left;
  width: 971px;
  height: 70px;
  background: url(../images/menu_bg.gif) no-repeat 0 0 #CCC
}
#menu ul {
  float: right;
  width: 936px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0 0 35px
}
#menu li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  font: 18px/20px"ZapfHumnst BT", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 27px 20px 27px;
  background: url(../images/menu_border.gif) no-repeat 0 0
}
#menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#menu li a.current {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none
}
#menu li.first {
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 27px 0 64px
}
#menu li.last {
  background: none;
  background: url(../images/menu_border.gif) no-repeat 0 2px;
  padding: 10px 0 27px 27px
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about_us.html">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="privacy.html">A True Story</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="current" href="projects.html">Menopause Overview</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li> -->
    <li><a href="support.html">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have not included any of the css you have written thus far.

Comment: Have you attempted to implement a dropdown behaviour for your menu yet? Without the context of a current approach, this question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Wobbles sorry i forgot to include it

Comment: @Serlite sorry i forgot to include it

Comment: Soooo. I see no nested menus here, what were you expecting to dropdown?

Comment: @Wobbles sorry, newbie here. i want to have a hoverable dropdown of my "menopause overview"

Comment: @JomNillasca where is that in the markup? I so no signs of an attempt to nest anything inside the `Menopause Overview` menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a pure css based dropdown menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu)

Comment: Eh...lots of existing questions on Stack Overflow regarding this. You need only to search, and I guarantee you'll find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @Wobbles markup? hm. lets assume there is attemp to nest like link 1 and link 2. please help! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a proper structure of the dropdown menu such as for instead this :

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about_us.html">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="privacy.html">A True Story</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="current" href="projects.html">Menopause Overview</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="support.html">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, with the `:hover` event, you can show/hide the dropdown :

```
#menu li ul { display: none; position : absolute; left: 0; top: 50px; background: #333; width: auto; padding: 0;}
#menu li:hover ul {display: block; }
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2p75kyo/4/)

Comment: css is all you need, the `:hover` pseudo 'un hides' the popup.