# Sub menu on Hover with CSS

Tags: html, css, submenu

Initially, I struggled to show up a drop-down menu using the css for the theme which i downloaded from [here](https://themewagon.com/themes/office-responsive-multipage-bootstrap-template/). But based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu), i got an idea to do and completed showing up with the drop - down menu. But, presently, it shows up nicely as follows in normal browsers.

[image: normal browser view]

But, when i shrink the browser to look as if like a mobile view, the sub-menus are not aligned, How to show the sub-menu without any issues. ?

[image: Mobile View]

As you could see above, the `sub-menus` are not aligned properly. How could i achieve it.

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: If you think it's helpful for us to provide a fiddle, we also think it's helpful if you made one yourself to illustrate the problem

Comment: @liroP, I have downloaded the theme from https://themewagon.com/themes/office-responsive-multipage-bootstrap-template/  The theme is 'office master'

Comment: .active>ul { padding-left:0px;}

Comment: @MuzamilAbbas, I did but now it has gone to the left-most

Comment: @Keynes then give it some padding from left as you like. or give me your actual requirement.

Comment: @MuzamilAbbas, there are also many issues, the drop down has to appear on hower only, but now its shown up

Comment: @Keynes ok i am adding full answer to it. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Keynes i found a link for you hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu

Comment: #Muzamil Abbas, i have kept the menu somehow, but the links are not going in shrink view. can u help me here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622664/bootsrap-3-drop-down-submenu-links-not-working-in-mobile-view