# Bootsrap 3 drop - down submenu links not working in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, submenu

I created a drop down sub menu in bootstrap 3, in which the links are working (It goes to respective pages). But, While i shrink the browser to look as if like a mobile view, the links of the sub menus are not working(It goes to different page while the menu is clicked).

The following image depicts the issue with my issue.

[image: Links goes to another page]

From the above image, if i move the curser to click the 'tamil newsletter', it is moving to 'gallery' page.

I feel there is a simple solution for this issue and i do not know where i am wrong.

The following is my code:-

```
<nav id="navbar-section" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-sticky" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>

            <div id="navbar-spy" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/support_us'); ?>">Support Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Newsletter</a>
                       <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/tam_newsletter'); ?>">Tamil Newsletter</a></li>
                          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/eng_newsletter'); ?>">English Newsletter</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/gallery'); ?>"><span>Gallery</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/contact_us'); ?>"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav id="navbar-section" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-sticky" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

    </div>

    <div id="navbar-spy" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/support_us'); ?>">Support Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Newsletter</a>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/tam_newsletter'); ?>">Tamil Newsletter</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/eng_newsletter'); ?>">English Newsletter</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/gallery'); ?>"><span>Gallery</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/contact_us'); ?>"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bootstrap nav already... The pull-right which you added to dropdown-menu is creating the problem....

So as a quick patch, add this to you css.. add more specificity if there are other dropdown-menus on the page.

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
  #navbar-spy > .navbar-nav{
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    width: 170px;
  }
  #navbar-spy .dropdown-menu.pull-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  #navbar-spy .dropdown-menu.navbar-nav{
    margin:0;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #navbar-spy .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu.navbar-nav > li > a{
    padding:2px 10px 2px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
}
```

Comment: But Is it Possible to create sub-menus in bootstrap 3

Comment: I think there is no submenu component directly, but you can work with navbar and collapse components to get expected result... Or just go with jquery show hide if you are good at it

Comment: I Promise,presently, i dont have a css. If you help me, i will learn.. Then I tried code snippet, but my innocence i do not know to do.. But i tried above..

Comment: Sorry my bad I haven't had a good look at your code earlier, you are using bootstrap nav already. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes Finally, I arrived it. Thanks a lot . But is that any chance that, can we reduce the size of the sub menu.. I reduced margin to some extent.

Comment: Not exactly what size you are referring to. Updated the code to reduce font, paddings and margins a little

Comment: All done . I now only wants a divider between the sub menus.. i used `<li class="nav-divider"></li>` but it did not worked. how can i achieve it..

Comment: You don't need additional <li> for divider. Added css for divider and few more styles to make it look aligned. hope you like it.