# Make select element linked, including when selecting the current option

Tags: jquery, select

I'm using a `select` element to redirect users to a page when selected. The below code works fine, but not when reselecting the currently selected option, for example in the below, Term 3 does not link correctly. Is there a way to rewrite the line `window.location.href = currentSlug;` to work on any option selection?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="Term" data-slug="Term Link"></option>
    <option value="Term2" data-slug="Term2 Link"></option>
    <option value="Term3" data-slug="Term3 Link" selected></option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
// Vars
var select = $("select");

// On select change
$(document).on("change", select, function () {
  // Vars
  var currentSlug = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-slug");

  // Create link by redirecting window to data-slug
  // This works but not if selecting the option:selected option
  window.location.href = currentSlug;
});
```

Comment: In cases like this you would be better including a 'Go' button in your UI so that the user can action the already selected option. Then you hook the JS to that button instead. Alternatively, use a HTML dropdown structure which allows you to use `a` elements to invoke the redirects, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953516/519413

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. Is there a solution to the above however?

Comment: Not a reliable one, no. You could potentially use the `click` event on the `option` instead of `change` on the `select`, but that has a lot of potential edge cases you would need to handle, and support on mobile devices is patchy at best