# Select Option, with anchor

Tags: html

how would I transform the below code into a `<select> <option>` drop down? Currently when I select any one of the links below it filters out a list only showing the selected items.

```
<span>Filters:</span>
<a class="button" href="#all">All</a>
<a class="button" href="#settings">Settings</a>
<a class="button" href="#categories">Categories</a>
```

**trying to do something like this**

```
<select>
<option class="button" href="#all">All</option>
<option class="button" href="#settings">Settings</option>
<option class="button" href="#categories">Categories</option>
...
```

Comment: I find that the standard dropdownlist is very limited when it comes to anything beyond standard option elements. You might want to look at third party dropdowns for this

Comment: You are missing the JavaScript attached to the `<a>`.

Comment: maybe this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correctly you want your link to behave like a select box. [http://jsfiddle.net/aatZJ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/aatZJ/4/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.change()` may help you.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

Why not add an onClick event to your option elements?

just set the location.href to your required value inside every onclick.