# How to get a link beside the content in select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

select tag:-

```
<%=select_tag "names",options_from_collection_for_select(@users,"id","name",@user.id)%>
```

Right now my dropdown looks like this:-

```
john
matt
sara
```

But I want to have it like:-

```
 john edit
 matt edit
 sara  edit
```

Where "edit" is the link which can edit a particular user.But I am not able to put a link into select_tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this in Rails out of the box - this is rather uncommon task. Yet I see two options here:

1. use solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag);
2. find yourself a suitable jQuery plugin like [this](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/). Most of them will turn the `select` tag into `divs`, which can be further customized.