# Links in <select> dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

Is it possible for each dropdown options to link somewhere when selected without the need for an external button?

```
<select>
  <option value="x">x</option>
  <option value="y">y</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is certainly easy to do.  Have you done any research into how you might do this?

Comment: yes but you need javascript to do it. I'll make you a fiddle. Stay tuned!

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/X8WUG/ ?

Comment: @j08691, you could have answered it instead of a comment.

Comment: @SheikhHeera - except I wan't sure if that was what the OP was after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using href links inside <option> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag/2000689#2000689

Answer (score 92):

You can use the onChange property.  Something like:

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="www.google.com">A</option>
    <option value="www.aol.com">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: indeed it is onChange; onValueChanged is not javascript

Answer (score 40):

Add an onchange event handler and set the pages location to the value

```
<select id="foo">
    <option value="">Pick a site</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">x</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">y</option>
</select>

<script>
    document.getElementById("foo").onchange = function() {
        if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }        
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

... or if you want / need to keep your option 'value' as it was, just add a new attribute:

```
<select id="my_selection">
<option value="x" href="/link/to/somewhere">value 1</option>
<option value="y" href="/link/to/somewhere/else">value 2</option>
</select>

<script>
document.getElementById('my_selection').onchange = function() {
    window.location.href = this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help:

```html
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
 <option value="home.html">Home</option>
 <option value="contact.html">Contact</option>
 <option value="about.html">About</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, I know but for 2019 peeps:

Like above if you just want to change the URL you can do this:

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="www.google.com">A</option>
    <option value="www.aol.com">B</option>
</select>
```

But if you want it to act like an a tag and so you can do `"./page"`, `"#bottom"` or `"?a=567"` use `window.location.replace()`

```
<select onChange="window.location.redirect(this.value)">
    <option value="..">back</option>
    <option value="./list">list</option>
    <option value="#bottom">bottom</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What if I want to open the link in a new tab (like the target="_blank") with some rel="" too?

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @kevin's answer,
if someone has to perform some confirmation logic if URL is critical.

```
<select onChange=" this.options[this.selectedIndex].text == 'Delete' ? "Confirmation logic" : window.location.href=this.value;" >
    <option selected disabled>Action</option>    
    <option value="/user/view">View</option>    
    <option value="/user/edit">Edit</option>    
    <option value="/user/delete">Delete</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this code:

```
<select id="menu" name="links" size="1" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
    <option value="URL">Book</option>
    <option value="URL">Pen</option>
    <option value="URL">Read</option>
    <option value="URL">Apple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Is it too hard to change URL for desired address?