# How to change href link of button used with dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am trying to create drop down menu with a button.

My code is -

```
<div class="dropdown-plans">
<select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle">
<option value="tri"> 3 Years - Rs. 100/month </option>
<option value="bi"> 2 Years - Rs. 200/month </option>
<option value="ann"> 1 Year - Rs. 100/month </option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="button-plans">
<a href="somelink"> Order now </a>
</div>
```

Depending on what option i select from dropdown, the href value "somelink" should change.
For instance if i select 1 year. href value should change from "somelink" to "google.com"

Update:

I searched two things. 1) Changing href using javascript and 2) using onchange for select tag. It lead me to create this following piece of code.

```
<script>

function getOpt(period) {

    if (period.value = "tri") { document.getElementById("abc").href="tri.html"; }
    else if (period.value = "bi") { document.getElementById("abc").href="bi.html"; }
    else { document.getElementById("abc").href="ann.html"; } 
 }

</script>

<div class="dropdown-plans">

<select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle" onchange="getOpt(this)">

<option value="tri"> 3 Years - Rs. 100/month </option>
<option value="bi"> 2 Years - Rs. 200/month </option>
<option value="ann"> 1 Year - Rs. 100/month </option>

</select>

</div>

<div class="button-plans">
<a id="abc" href="something"> Order now </a>
</div>
```

Problem: The drop down shows 3 years by default. But if i select 2 years, it still remains 3 years.

Comment: I have tried something, check the updated post. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287672/links-in-select-dropdown-options
post of kevin worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to change the `href` to the value of the selected option:

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown-plans">
    <select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle">
        <option value="tri">3 Years - Rs. 100/month</option>
        <option value="bi">2 Years - Rs. 200/month</option>
        <option value="ann">1 Year - Rs. 100/month</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="button-plans">
    <a id="abc" href="something"> Order now </a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var sel = document.getElementById('basic_plan');
sel.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("abc").href = this.value + ".html";
}
```

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MHh46/1/)**

Comment: Yep that works fine. Thank you. However check my post for updated code. And see if you can answer my doubt.

Comment: @Codestor when you use `=` you are telling the select to have that value, so you are always in the first if. You should use `==` to compare values

Comment: @Codestor, I updated my answer with corrections and optimization to your code, please don't use inline script like `onchange="getOpt(this)"`

Comment: Thank you. I learned so many things. This was my first post on stack overflow and I am happy with the quick response.

I was using if else to select tri, bi, ann dot html. However you used a concat + operator. That was clever. 

Also document.querySelector. I am eager to learn more about it now.

Comment: @Codestor, happy I could help. Enjoy SO!

Comment: Oh okay. I got it. Script should boot up after every HTML element is rendered. :)

Comment: Just a small correction. If i am using the script before html then window.onload works instead of window.load. :)

Comment: Simple and quick solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for this task.

Working code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#basic_plan').change(function(e) {
    var an = $(this).val();
    switch(an){         

case "ann": $('.button-plans a').attr('href',"google.com"); break;
case "bi": $('.button-plans a').attr('href',"yahoo.com"); break;
case "tri": $('.button-plans a').attr('href',"bing.com"); break;
            /* and so on*/
        }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown-plans">
<select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle">
<option value="tri"> 3 Years - Rs. 100/month </option>
<option value="bi"> 2 Years - Rs. 200/month </option>
<option value="ann"> 1 Year - Rs. 100/month </option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="button-plans">
<a href="somelink"> Order now </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No jQuery tagged in this question... maybe good to name that this answer has jQuery somewhere in your answer.

Comment: The code definitely works. Thank you. However i would surely love to learn more about my doubt in this post. Check my updated post. And thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript code to change the href attribute.
The javascript function should be called on onChange eventof select list and the function will change the href of the link according to the selected option.

Code:

```
<select onchange="jsFunction()" id="dd">
....

</select>



function jsFunction(){

var e = document.getElementById("dd");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

// on the basiss of value of strUser change the href value
    document.getElementById("abc").href="xyz.php"; 


}
```