# How to link option tags to other pages in html?

Tags: html, css

am having difficulties in linking my pages. Have tried all the tricks I know(basic knowledge, because I just started learning web designing am actually a graphic designer and I only have the basic knowledge in html and css I have NO clue in js or php and the rest. just to let you know.) but nothing is working. hope you guess can help me.  below are the codes..

```
    <div class="fleft">
        <ul id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
            <option value="-1" selected>OUR SERVICES</option>
            <option class="icon-corporate">Corporate Branding</option>
            <option class="icon-logo">Logo Designing</option>
            <option class="icon-webdesign">Web Designing</option>
            <option class="icon-camera">Photography</option>
            <option class="icon-video">Video Editting</option>
            <option class="icon-art">Illustration</option>
            <option class="icon-work">Graphic Design</option>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Also if you are using a select box then you may want to include the `<select>` tag instead of the `<ul>` which can only contain `<li>` as a child.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, are you trying to use a drop-down box or a list?

For a drop-down, as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287672/links-in-select-dropdown-options), you can do the following with JavaScript.  Use the `onChange` event to specify what to do when the value of the selection box is changed.  Then use `window.location` to tell the browser to navigate to a specific page.

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="www.google.com">A</option>
    <option value="www.aol.com">B</option>
</select>
```

For a list, simply change your syntax a bit.  Use a unordered list and then style it to your liking.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="www.google.com"">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.aol.com">B</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Such a great solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can't link them per se.

If you want a list of links, then you should have an actual list of links:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to use a select menu then you should note that:

1. It is designed for use as part of a form
2. It is relatively unfriendly to search engines
3. It gives a UI that doesn't indicate to the user that it is a navigational tool

Then (note that steps 4 and onwards are optional):

1. Add a form and remove the unordered list
2. Add a `<input type="submit" value="Go">` button
3. Write a server side program (referenced in the `action` attribute of the form) that checks what the value of the select is, and then outputs a `302 Found` HTTP status and a `Location` header with the URL you wish the browser to go to.
4. Add a JavaScript event handler (either on the form's `submit` event or the select's `change` event)
5. Have it check the value of the selected option
6. Set the `location` property to the desired destination
7. Cancel the default behaviour of the form

Answer (score 0):

If you what to create menu using ul you can use same this

```
 <div class="fleft">
            <ul id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
                <li value="-1" selected>OUR SERVICES</li>
                <li class="icon-corporate">Corporate Branding</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

If you need drop down you should use

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```