# enable each drop-down item to link to another page

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

I want to enable each drop-down item to link to another page. but i dont know how to link it to another page. can someone help me please? this is for my project. im using php in dreamweaver.

```
<li class="current"><a href="location.php">Location</a>
                    <ul>

                        <li style="display: table-row"><a href="#">A</a></li>                           
                        <li style="display: table-row"><a href="#">B</a></li>
                        <li style="display: table-row"><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        <li style="display: table-row"><a href="#">D</a></li>
                        <li style="display: table-row"><a href="#">E</a></li>
                        <li style="display: table-row"><a href="#">F</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: you need to be more specific about the problem. Share some code or a problem please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link, meaning transfer its data through a form submission? If yes, you can retrieve the data from another page via $_GET and $_POST methods.

page1.php

```
<form method = "POST" action="page2.php"> // you may use GET
    <select name = "dropDown" required>
        <option value = "Sample Value">Sample Value</option>
        <option value = "Sample Value">Sample Value</option>
        <option value = "Sample Value">Sample Value</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submitForm" value = "Submit Form">
</form>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitForm']))
{
   $displayData = $_POST['dropDown'];
   echo $displayData;
}
?>
```

Or you mean by link using "href", you can use

```
<a href = "https://www.google.com/" target = "_blank">Link</a>
```

Hope this helps you! :)

Comment: thank u for the help :). but what i mean is that i want that link page to be a new page. should i need to create another .php? how to do that?

Comment: You mean, you want to open the location.php on a new window or tab?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help you. I think you mean .php as in the extention filename??

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12287729/4282030