# Reference select menu HTML in javascript

Tags: java, html, select, menu, reference

I am brand new to html and fairly new to coding in general. I know this is basic but I find adapting someone elses code for my needs helps me learn much faster than just going through tutorials.

I want to create a currency exchange site. I would like to select a currency, enter the ammount, and see how much I would get in £ in return.

my code;

```js
function Converter(){

  if (document.converter.currency.value = EUR)

    document.converter.pound.value = document.converter.ammount.value * 0.9


  if (document.converter.currency.value = USD)

    document.converter.pound.value = document.converter.ammount.value * 0.6
}
```

```html
<form name="converter">
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name = "currency">
        <option value="EUR" selected> Euro </option>
        <option value="USD">Dollar</option></select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" name="ammount" onChange="Converter()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>£:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="pound" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I would like to know if this is the right way to do this and mainly, how to refernce the select menu in javascript.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
function Converter(){

  if (document.converter.currency.value == 'EUR')

  document.converter.pound.value = document.converter.ammount.value * 0.9 ;


  if (document.converter.currency.value == 'USD')

  document.converter.pound.value = document.converter.ammount.value * 0.6 ;
}
```

```html
<form name="converter">
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name = "currency">
        <option value="EUR" selected> Euro </option>
        <option value="USD">Dollar</option></select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" name="ammount" onkeyup="Converter()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>£:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="pound" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

There is an event [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp), which fired after a change in element and on focusout . You can use [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)/[onkeydown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) to get result on key up.

And in your script part you are assigning value . [Check](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script language="JavaScript">

function Converter(){

if (document.converter.currency.value = "EUR") //fix here

document.converter.pound.value = document.converter.ammount.value * 0.9


if (document.converter.currency.value = "USD") // also fix here

document.converter.pound.value = document.converter.ammount.value * 0.6
}
</script>
```

You were missing some much needed quotes, fix those. And for the DOM related part, [this thread might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287672/links-in-select-dropdown-options)

Answer (score 0):

Are you against using JQuery? You could actually use AJAX to fetch up-to-date rates from a service like [fixer.io](http://fixer.io/). This will make sure your conversion rates remain accurate.

The syntax for doing all of this is considerably simpler in JQuery, but it can be done in vanilla JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // update on input
  $("#amount").on("input", function() {
    var currency = $("#converter option:selected").val();
    convertCurrency(currency);
  });

  // update on select menu change
  $("#converter").change(function() {
    convertCurrency($(this).val());
  });
});

// convert currency using live rates from fixer.io
function convertCurrency(currency){
  var amount = $("#amount").val();
  $.get("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=GBP", function(data) {
    var baseExchange = (amount / data.rates[currency]).toFixed(2);
    var commission = (baseExchange * 0.1).toFixed(2);
    // calculations
    $("#gbpBase").html(baseExchange);
    $("#commission").html(commission);
    $("#gbpTotal").html((baseExchange - commission).toFixed(2));
  });
}
```

```css
#results-table {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container jumbotron' style='padding-top: 0.5rem;'>
  <h4>Convert to GBP (£)</h4>
  <hr/>
  <table class='table table-striped'>
    <thead>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class='form-control' name="currency" id="converter">
            <option value="EUR" selected>Euro (€)</option>
            <option value="USD">US Dollar ($)</option>            
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class='form-control' type="text" name="amount" placeholder='Enter amount' id="amount" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="table" id="results-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Base Exchange</th>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;£: <span id="gbpBase">0.00</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Commission (10%)</th>
        <td>- £: <span id='commission'>0.00</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Exchange Amount</th>
        <td><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;£: <span id="gbpTotal">0.00</span></strong></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Updated **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/OjJPdw)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really appreciate it!! This is awesome although is it possible to add a set markup to the market rate  ( for instance market rate +10% comission). Seems a little out my coding league, but ill have a play about with it and see if i can do it myself!

Comment: Do you subtract the 10% commission from the exchange amount? I'm not familiar with the foreign exchange business, but I added an updated [link](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/OjJPdw). It does "(converted amount) - (10% of the converted amount)" ... I hope it helps

Comment: When converting money, a higher rate is worse for the base currency being returned (its being divided by a bigger number). What you have done is essentially the same thing, though, just more explicitly. Thank you so much for your time!