# Is there anyway to make actionlinks work inside a dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there anyway to make this work:

```
<select>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("View", "View", "Person")</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Person")</option>
    </select>
```

So it's basically a dropdown full of links. When you click a link it should direct to the action method like a normal ActionLink helper.

Comment: Might want to look at this question...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the change event of the select to open the links, like this:

html:

```
<select>
    <option>@Url.Action("View", "View", "Person")</option>
    <option>@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit", "Edit")</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
$('select').change(function(){ window.href = $(this).find(':selected').text();});
```