# Html.ActionLink does not work in a html option tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

It's my first time using "select-option" tags, so please help me with this.

Here is my problem:
I have created this for exporting data into different type of files (xls, doc, etc.):

```html
<select class="btn btn-xs">
                    <option selected>Export to....</option>
                    <option>@Html.ActionLink("Export to Word", "ExportToWord", "Stock", FormMethod.Post)</option>
                    <option>@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "Excel", "Stock", FormMethod.Post)</option>
                </select>
```

it allows me to select the type of export I choose, but it does not export the data. So I researched a little but I did not found something to help me.

Here is an example: [Is there anyway to make actionlinks work inside a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309422/is-there-anyway-to-make-actionlinks-work-inside-a-dropdown) or the other from this link: [using href links inside <option> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag). But I don't understand if all the code is inside the same controller how to do this?

Comment: Because its invalid html (the only permitted content is text)

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: `select` and `option` are form tags. `a` tags aren't valid there which are links.

Comment: So if I do this: "<option>Export to Excel</option>", how can I use it so that When I choose it to do the export?

Comment: Use javascript to handle the `.change()` event of the `<select>` (but its bad design - let the user make their selection, then click a button to do the redirect)

Comment: I understand what you are saying: make that select and a button that does the export based on the selected value(for this I need something like a ID, to select that value?).

Comment: Actually this is a bad idea UX-wise. Represent these actions using individual buttons. Not lease because:
- change in the dropdown would result in undesired effects if the user uses keyboard to switch between the elements - then an onchange event would fire every time the user picks a new one.
- since generating a word/excel file is costly (compared to just rendering an HTML page) you should use POST requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an element inside an option tag (action link will create an a tag).
If you want to move to a link that is selected from a dropdown you'll want it to happen on the change event.
Use an attribute that has the address inside like
`<option value="http://stackoverflow.com">`.
Have the change event look at the value attribute and use that.

Example:

```js
$('#dropdownID').on("change", function () {
  var ddURL = $('option:selected', this).attr('value');
  window.location.href = ddURL;
});
```

Comment: Can you share an example please.

Comment: Example added. Bear in mind, users probably won't expect a page to change like that on a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: updated answer with the selector you'd want. Let me know if that works for you