# MVC add link to jQuery Simple Effects Dropdown List

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/

I have put the Simple Effects Dropdown List jQuery control into my MVC application and need to know how I can add links to the select options so I can use it to navigate my views.  The markup is a Select input control.

Comment: have you tried something as simple as `<option><a></a></option>` ?...

Comment: Yes, this does nothing <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
       <option value="-1" selected>Select</option>
       <option value="1" class="icon-google-plus"><a href="http://google.co.uk">Google Plus</a></option>
       <option value="2" class="icon-facebook">Facebook</option>
       <option value="3" class="icon-twitter">Twitter</option>
       <option value="4" class="icon-github">GitHub</option>
      </select>

Comment: ahh, here ya go: [using href links inside <option> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

Comment: I've tried that too, I think the problem is that this jQuery control renders the Select control as span elements on the page so this is stripped out.

Comment: The Simple Effects control changes the default structure of the option list into a series of <span>s. You may need to study the "js/jquery.dropdown.js" file to manually manipulate the <span>s
If you want to use this control, my suggestion will be to create another button to direct you to the selected link.

Comment: Thanks all, I have managed this by editing jquery.dropdown.js - it defines its output like so '<li data-value="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></li>'  - I modified this to include an anchor tag supplying the val as the link:  '<li data-value="' + val + '"><a href="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></a></li>'   - and supplied an MVC friendly link like: value="~/jQuery/index"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I have managed this by editing jquery.dropdown.js - it defines its output like so

```
<li data-value="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></li>
```

I modified this to include an anchor tag supplying the val as the link:

```
<li data-value="' + val + '"><a href="' + val + '"><span class="' + classes + '">' + label + '</span></a></li>
```

- and supplied an MVC friendly link as the value in the select list like: value="~/jQuery/index"