# How can I change the page by using html and css?

Tags: html

```
  <select>

    <option value="index.html">Home</option>
    enter code here
    <option value="about.html">About Us</option>

    <option value="smt.html">Smt</option>

    <option value="smt.html">Smt</option>

  </select>
```

- What is wrong in it ? why isn't changed the page by the time selecting an option?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: <select id="nav_item"  >
                    <option >Choose</option>
                    <option value="#">Home</a></option>
                     <option>Washroom</option>
                    <option>Offices</option>
                    <option>Care Homes</option>
                     <option>Hotels and Hospitality</option>
                     <option>Comercial Premises</option>
                     <option>Private Residences</option>
                     <option>Contact Us</option>
                 </select>

Comment: possible duplicate of [using href links inside <option> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the form of the post method you can set it to the selected value.

```
  <select name="menu"  onchange="this.form.action=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```