# Angular ui-sref on dropdown not working

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app with routing. I have a dropdown select defined as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" id="transactiontype" ng-model="tt">
    <option><a ui-sref="cash">Cash</a></option>
    <option><a ui-sref="cheque">Cheque</a></option>
    <option><a ui-sref="debitcard">Debit</a></option>
    <option><a ui-sref="creditcard">Credit</a></option>
</select>
```

When i select one of the dropdowns, somehow it is not loading the view i am referencing. Where am i going wrong? I also tried this:

```
<option ui-sref="creditcard">Credit</option>
```

Comment: We need to see the router config to answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider using ng-options instead:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {    
$scope.options = [
  { label: 'Cash', value: 'cash' },
  { label: 'Cheque', value: 'cheque' },
  { label: 'Debit', value: 'debit' },
  { label: 'Credit', value: 'credit' }
];
$scope.$watch('tt', function(value) {
  if(value) {
    $state.go(value);
  }
});
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <select class="form-control" id="transactiontype" ng-model="tt" ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options">
  </select>
</div>
```

EDIT: Agree with what @Likwid_T said, I think ng-change is the best choice to detect the change in select tag. I just forgot about it at that moment. So please refer to his answer too. Good day.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure it's because the a tags won't work inside the select - option tags.

As per this SO question: [using href link inside option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

Try writing a function that will redirect the page and trigger it based on the select change or maybe your model change, whatever it best for your program.

something like:

```
<select class="form-control" id="transactiontype" ng-model="tt" ng-change="locationChangeFunction()">
...
</select>
```

Your controller might look like:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state){

    $scope.locationChangeFunction = function(){
         $state.go($scope.tt);
    }
}]);
```

**EDIT**

Use a combination of both solutions (credit to Hieu TB):

```
<select class="form-control" id="transactiontype" ng-model="tt" ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options" ng-change="locationChangeFunction()"></select>
```

*ng-change* will wait for the model change, which will change the DOM, which will trigger the change, now you're not running a resource consuming $watch function

Comment: @Hieu TB's method might be a more relaibale to go, you'd have to try it, I'd rather do the change on an event because .$watch is essentially a function that runs all the time, whereas on the event (like ng-change) you only run the function when you need to.  However I don't know if the ng-change will fire before or after the model changes, even if it does you might just have a race condition, however with $watch you KNOW the model changed.  I'd still try to find a way to do it with an event rather than watch because if you change your model for any other reason, you're changing page again.

Comment: Thank @Likwid_T to point out this. I think "ng-change" is the best too, just because I too eagle to answer the question and forget about it. I had already given your answer my up vote, :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution ended up just using a generic href, but using the old ng-router declaration with a '#/' prefix.  For example: instead of using...

```
<select class="form-control" id="transactiontype" ng-model="tt">
    <option><a ui-sref="cash">Cash</a></option>
    <option><a ui-sref="cheque">Cheque</a></option>
    <option><a ui-sref="debitcard">Debit</a></option>
    <option><a ui-sref="creditcard">Credit</a></option>
</select>
```

Try using href with '#/' prefix like so...

```
<select class="form-control" id="transactiontype" ng-model="tt">
    <option><a href="#/cash">Cash</a></option>
    <option><a href="#/cheque">Cheque</a></option>
    <option><a href="#/debitcard">Debit</a></option>
    <option><a href="#/creditcard">Credit</a></option>
</select>
```