# Select form with links?

Tags: html, select-menu

Im trying to use a select form as my primary navigation instead of a custom drop down menu. Is there a way to use  tags to link to other pages within the site as would a typical drop down menu?

This is what I have tried to do thus far, but doesn't appear to be working

**HTML**

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">

    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="sticky_on: small medium large">
        <div class="menu">
           <select>
                <option><a href="work.html">Work</a></option>
                <option><a href="studio.html">Studio</a></option>
                <option><a href="ideas.html">Ideas</a></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

See link here; http://hardystewartdesign.com/dist/project.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag

Comment: anchor tags behave differently in option tag, see above link