# change form target based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, target

I want every dropdown option to have a target of "_blank" except option 4.  How do I switch the target based on the option selected in the form?

```
    <form action="mypage.php" method="post" target="_blank" />
<input type="hidden" name="turnaround" value="20">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Platform</td>
        <td>
            <select required id="cu" name="plat" style="min-width: 120px;">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2 (Desktop Only)</option>
                <option value="3">3 (Mobile Only)</option>
                <option value="4">4 (Wildcard)</option>
                <option value="5">Catch-All</option>        
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div><input type="submit" value="Select Platform" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't hardcode them?  Also, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag) may help.

Comment: Also there is typo in your code, there is `/` at the end of starting form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpaxe217/)

js:

```
$("#cu").on("change",function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    if(a == "4"){
         $("#formId").removeAttr("target")
    }else{
    $("#formId").attr("target","_blank")
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

give your form an id:

```
<form action="mypage.php" id="myForm" method="post" target="_blank" />
<input type="hidden" name="turnaround" value="20">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Platform</td>
        <td>
            <select required id="cu" name="plat" style="min-width: 120px;">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2 (Desktop Only)</option>
                <option value="3">3 (Mobile Only)</option>
                <option value="4">4 (Wildcard)</option>
                <option value="5">Catch-All</option>        
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

your js:

```
$('#myForm').attr("target") = $('#cu').val() == "4" ? "" : "_blank";
```

not tested but it should work

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to give class or id to submit button.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
    if($('#cu').val() == '4'){
        $(this).closest('form').prop('target','');    
    }  
});
```