# How can I redirect to specific URL on select change?

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown-menu that I auto populate base on my Ajax call. I want to redirect to specific URL on select change.

---

**jQuery**

```
// Auto Populate the dropdown-menu
$("#dd").append('<option value="' + userId + '"> <a href="">' + name + '</a></option>');
```

Thanks

Comment: Because it isn't valid HTML markup, don't expect it to work. Explain isntead why would you need that? Sounds like on `select`change, redirect to specific URL

Comment: short answer is no...it;s invalid html and doesn't make any sense either

Comment: What did I missed there ? I couldn't tell. Hope u don't mind point it out.

Comment: anchor tags cannot go inside option tags

Comment: While this is invalid HTML (for the reasons stated), there are non-native/emulated drop-down lists (found in various UI libraries) that support all sort of extras including rich content.

Comment: @A.Wolff : "Sounds like on selectchange, redirect to specific URL" - you're right, that is exactly, what I am trying to do

Comment: Just read the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html

Comment: Create a custom dropdown component to support html in options, in native select its not allowed.

Comment: @vinayakj : Thank-you for the tip. I didn't know that.

Comment: @A.Wolff : selectchange, redirect to specific URL , can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: `onchange= location.href=this.value`

Comment: @开发人员 Instead close/delete this question and ask a new one

Comment: When you insert an HTML element inside an element where it shouldn't be, the browser will try to fix the structure so that it will display the way it was intended. Similarly if you insert a `<h1>` inside a `<p>` the browser will remove the `<h1>` and place it outside.

Comment: <option> tags cannot contain any other tags. If you want to do it then you need to used other plugin which will create a wrapper on your select dropdown like select2 plugin

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag

Comment: For every item (option) for value put Your URL location and `onchange="window.location=this.value"`

Comment: @nelek : Can you please link your suggestion with part of my code ?

Comment: @abs : I update my post, can you help me make it happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend reading about HTML tags.

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">

function myFunction() {
  //Redirect to URL 
}
```

Ready more at [onchange Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp), [JavaScript Window Location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Cheers !

Comment: Do I need to do anything else in my `option` tag ? Can you be a little more details ?

Comment: Function will be invoked whenever you change the selected value. You need to write logic in function, you may want to read selected value.