# Need to get an href tag to work with select option in a foreach loop using php echo

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to add an href link onto a drop-down select option using a foreach loop to grab the data from database. The code shows up but when I select the month it does not take me to google.com Anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this or is it even possible?

```
  <select class="form-control">
            <?php 

            foreach($records as $r)
            { 

               echo '<a href="http://google.com">'. '<option value="'.$r->month.'">'.$r->month.'</option>'.'</a>';

               echo '<option value="'.$r->notice.'">'.$r->notice.'</option>';
         }
            ?>

</select>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using href links inside <option> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

Comment: this is not duplicate totally different question. I need anchor tag inside a foreach loop that link does not show me how it can be done also I am using php with echo command

Comment: sorry for maybe sounding frustrated i been at this for hours. once i figure it out will post answere

Comment: Do you have any javascript code to navigate to google.com upon selecting an option?

Comment: no have not tried yet looking into that now

Comment: but what gets complicated is i am going to use a url from mysql database to fill in the data  which will also need to be in the foreach loop

Comment: i my have to scrap this may be to complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out and this is the simplest way of doing it and it is working using the database to grab the data and the url.

```
   <select class="form-control" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
        <?php 


        foreach($records as $r)
        { 


          echo '<option value="'.$r->url.'">'.$r->month.'</option>';
           echo '<option value="'.$r->notice.'">'.$r->notice.'</option>';


     }
        ?>

        </select>
```

Comment: also I realized I can use a bootstrap modal to do what I need. But this was learning experience for me

Answer (score 0):

yo are doing wrong 
you can use jquery func on change drop selection
like here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">      </script>
   <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("input").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text">

<p>Write something in the input field, and then press enter or click outside the field.</p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is for input i need a dropdown select command in a foreach loop with an anchor tag attached to the option

Comment: you need to change input to option

Comment: how does it get me to go to google.com by selecting just one option if i have multiple options

Comment: you save url like google.com in value and than get value than use window.location.assign(url);