# Link displays as regular text

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, href

I have this code

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/forums/getForums",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var toAppend = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    toAppend += '<option>' + data[i]['Name'] + '</option>';
                    toAppend += '<a href="AddForum.html">Add new forum</a>';
                }

                $("#forums").append(toAppend)
            }
       });
```

And this is what I get

[image]

'Add new forum' should be link but it's not, it's just regular text and I can't click on it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `forums`? seems a `<SELECT>`

Comment: You cannot have link inside a `select`

Comment: If you want to add anchor link in `select option` then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)!

Comment: yep should specify what the #forums html tag !

Comment: Share html too. If you are having multiple elements with id `forums` then consider using class, or use `$("[id='forums']")`.

Comment: @MilanChheda that's was the problem. I replaced it with list so now everything is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: But now I have another question. Is there a way I can send that forum's name while clicking on link? I am adding a new topic by clicking on that link, not new forum like I first wrote, that's typo. I need to know forum's name so I know to what forum I am adding new topic. I hope you understand what I'm asking.