# How to add <a> tag in dropdown option value

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need to add option **value + a tag** along with that and I need to take an action when clicking on that a tag like following.

[image]

[image]

I tried with something like following

```
<select>
<option value="1">Free <a> select<a></option>
<option value="1">Pro <a> buy<a></option>
<option value="1">Unlimited <a> buy<a></option>
</select>
```

but option value should not contains html tags so it gets removed when goes to DOM. Any idea how to make this happen?

Comment: Make a custom version of the select box? Or maybe just have an `onchange` that brings you to the site?

Comment: _“Any idea how to make this happen?”_ - assuming how confusing this could be to users, who expect a select field to work a certain way, I would probably say, best not at all ... Plus, it makes rather little sense IMHO to present me with an option to select, as if I was just changing some setting, when you actually want me to go and buy this first.

Comment: @CBroe you are correct. will reconsider the design. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `<option>` cannot have any tags inside.

Maybe try something like this?

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/#

If you want to redirect to a link when clicked on the option, you may use something like this:

[using href links inside <option> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

Comment: I am also trying to achieve this using `<ul>`