# unable to trigger flask view function using href inside a tag inside select

Tags: python, html, flask

I have `select` inside the html

```
<select class="js-select2 partner_list" id="partner_option" name="partner_list_select" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value = "choose">Choose an option</option>
      <option value = "active_partner"><a href="{{url_for('active_partners')}}">Active Partners</a></option>
      <option value = "filter_partner">Filter/Edit Partner</option>
      <option value = "add_new_partner">New Partner</option>
</select>
```

triggering `myfunction()` works fine on selecting the option.

I want to run a `flask view function` when `Active Partner` option is selected

I did import `url_for`

`from flask import url_for`

I have a simple print command when the this flask view function is called

**server.py**

```
@app.route('/all_active_partners')
def active_partners() :
    print('HERE#############################')
    return redirect('/')
```

When i click on the option `Active Partners`, the active_partners `flask view function` never gets called!

when I load this link `http://127.0.0.1:5000/all_active_partners`

I get

`HERE#############################`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you check response in browser ( chrome inspect ) when you hit URL ?

Comment: Did check just now don't know how this would help!

Comment: redirect will give you response code, are you getting any response ?

Comment: Response `127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2019 16:45:12] "GET /all_active_partners HTTP/1.1" 302`

Comment: can you output what you're getting from following commang, curl -v 127.0.0.1/all_active_partners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select class="js-select2 partner_list" id="partner_option" name="partner_list_select" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value = "choose">Choose an option</option>
      <option value = "active_partner"><a href="{{url_for('active_partners')}}">Active Partners</a></option>
      <option value = "filter_partner">Filter/Edit Partner</option>
      <option value = "add_new_partner">New Partner</option>
</select>
```

[using href links inside option tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag) wouldn't work for `links`!

Had to use `ul` and `li` instead for links

```
<header id="header">
    <ul class="links" style="--items: 3;">
        <li class="active" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="{{url_for('active_partners')}}">Active Partner</a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none"><a href="#">Filter/Edit Partner</a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none"><a href="#">New Partner</a></li>
        <span class="line"></span>
    </ul>
</header>
```