# making a dropdown menu clickable and redirecting

Tags: html

I'm trying to make my "droplist" clickable and redirects it onto another page. Computer components in my case.
My code looks like this and the list works perfectly but the titles are not clickable.

HTML:

```css
 .collection-sort{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection-sort">
  <label>Filtrera:</label>
  <select>
    <option value="1"><a href="grafikkort.css">Grafikkort</a></option>
    <option value="2"><a href="processor.css">Processor</a></option>
    <option value="3"><a href="minne.css">Minne</a></option>
    <option value="4"><a href="moderkort.css">Moderkort</a></option>
    <option value="5"><a href="veckansklipp.css">Veckans Klipp</a></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using href links inside <option> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine now.

```css
  .collection-sort{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

```html
<div class="collection-sort">
        <label>Filtrera:</label>
        <select onchange="location = this.value;">
          <option value="grafikkort.css">Grafikkort</option>
          <option value="processor.css">processor</option>
          <option value="minne.css">minne</option>
          <option value="moderkort.css">moderkort</option>
          <option value="veckansklipp.css">veckansklipp</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect! Do I customize these new pages in the CSS?

Comment: Glad it helps.Customize? Explain.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanations. What I meant were if I fix and customize these new pages in CSS cause I currently just get the error message "Cannot GET /Webb%20Projekt1%20Fotboll/Web%20Try2/moderkort.css" if I press one of them. Thanks!

Comment: The value is the location of the CSS file

It may be in css/processor.css 

value="css/processor.css"

Comment: I solved it by making new files called "processor.css". This is a perfect example of a noobie mistake. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Axel Please consider to upvote the answer and to mark it as "Accepted".