# live search add a href to results

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, search, live

I have a live search in laravel 7
everything works good
but I cant add (href a tag) to result list
because result show in select option (select2 library) without (a) tag and cant be open in a new page for see result for this keyword

my blade:

```
   <div class="fre-search-wrap">
      <select class="livesearch form-control" name="Find Consultants"></select>
   </div>
```

my scripst:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.livesearch').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Consultants',
    ajax: {
        url: '/live_search/action',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 550,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.title,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

the main source was this
https://www.positronx.io/laravel-autocomplete-search-with-select2-example/

Comment: You may find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000689/5808894) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hello guy you can use this to add a tag:

```
$('.livesearch').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Consultants',
    ajax: {
        url: '/live_search/action',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 550,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: ""+item.title+"", // a tag
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).