# How to trigger links in select list with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I am new to jQuery in ASP.NET Core and can't handle this situation.
I have a table with data from database and selector with links to other project pages. They can't be triggered and I try to enforce triggering with jQuery.

CSHTML:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach(PersonViewModel pvm in Model)
   { <tr>
       <td><a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Person" asp-route-id="@pvm.Person.PersonID">@pvm.Person.FullName</a></td>
        <td>@pvm.Person.Age</td>
        .....        
         @if (pvm.Person.Records.Count != 0)
         {<td>               
            <select id=record_selector>
               @foreach(Record r in pvm.Person.Records)
               {
                    if(!r.IsHired){<option value=@r.RecordID>
                       <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Record" asp-route-id="@r.RecordID">Not Hired @r.RecordNumber</a></option>}
                    if(r.IsHired){<option value=@r.RecordID>
                       <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Record" asp-route-id="@r.RecordID">Hired @r.RecordNumber</a></option>}
               }
            </select>
         </td>}

          @if (pvm.Patient.Records.Count == 0)
          {<td><a asp-action="CreateUpdateRecord" asp-controller="Admin">Create new record</a></td>}    
   </tr>}
</tbody>
```

Later:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#record_selector").click(function(){
        $((this.children:selected).children("a")).click;
    });
});
```

I added jquery as a nuget package and a link  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in my layout file. It still doew not work. Could youhelp me please?

Comment: Check your browsers' console for error messages. The line `$((this.children:selected).children("a")).click;` already has multiple errors (not calling click, this.children:selected is not a valid js expression).

Comment: Sorry for this question, I found a more suitable solution.
I understand now that `<a>` tag cannot work in `<option>` tag ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-ta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag)g) and used this dropdown version [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown).
Thanks!