# ASP MVC -> How to use Select Tag with

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm trying to select products from a certain category but apparently it doesn't work that way.
I am applying the code from below.
Мy goal is to filter only the products of a certain category from a dropdown menu.

```
 public class SingleCategoryViewModel : IMapFrom<Data.Models.Category>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 public class ListCategoryViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SingleCategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
    }

//Controller

  public IActionResult ByName(int categoryId)
        {
            var viewModel = new ProductListViewModel()
            {
                Products = this._productService.GetByCategoryId<ProductInListViewModel>(categoryId),
            };

            return this.View(viewModel);
        }
//Service
  public IEnumerable<T> GetByCategoryId<T>(int categoryId)
        {
            var query = this.productRepository.All()
                .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId)
                .To<T>().ToList();

            return query;
        }


@using AspNetCoreTemplate.Web.ViewModels.Category;
@model ListCategoryViewModel


<select>

   
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {


        <option><a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="ByName" asp-route-   categoryId="@item.Id">@item.Name</a></option>


        }
</select>
```

Comment: can you send error?can you say more details?

Comment: No error .Nothing happens with this code ...                                                         
 <select>
    <option>All Categories</option>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {       
        <option><a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="ByName" asp-route- 
         categoryId="@item.Id"></a>@item.Name</option>
    }
  </select>

Comment: if i replace select tag with ul tag everything works normally

Comment: did you have problem with binding or routing?

Comment: No, everything is ok

Comment: i checked with test data ,bind data is okay, I think your problem is use tag a inside select ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000656/using-href-links-inside-option-tag

Comment: Please see this link as to how to pass a SelectListItem to a View and pass an ID back to the controller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc